# Android Storing icons locally or in database

Tags: android, icons

I'm working on an app where you are going to search for some item by some categories:
Main categories will be seen as icons and subcategories as a names(words).
I'm just wondering whether is better to store icon and names of subcategorien  in database or rather locally on device.

Comment: why don't you just add icons to your app as drawables & add String Array resources for the words if they aren't too many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to manage this data. If your table is continuously updated I advise you to store locally images and use database to retrive their path; otherwise, if your database is a static database and icons are small size then you can also think to store them into database in such a way that when someone installs and starts for the first time the App has to copy only once from assets or raw.

Comment: We going to implement something similar to your advice.
Thank you

Comment: If you really think my help useful, please check my answer. Thanks.